# Function in SQL for JOIN condition

Tags: sql-server, function

This is my query:

```
SELECT main.SomeValues, mainData.Name
  FROM dbo.MainTable main JOIN 
       dbo.MainDataTable mainData ON 
            (main.dataId = mainData.dataId) AND 
            (mainData.Type = 1 OR mainData.Type = 2 OR mainData.Type = 3)
```

I use similar query in many views. But the last condition is always the same everywhere: `main.Type = 1 OR main.Type = 2 OR main.Type = 3`.

I wondering how I can extract it to some SQL function. I never do any function before.

So it would be looks like this:

```
SELECT main.SomeValues, mainData.Name
FROM dbo.MainTable main
JOIN dbo.MainDataTable mainData ON main.dataId = mainData.dataId
       AND (GetConditionForType())  -- more or less ;)
```

Comment: Don't do it. Nothing wrong with writing it every time. SQL != OOP

Comment: Don't Use this, the direct where is better than dynamic sql

Comment: I understand your point of view, but some day probably these Type will change. For example only Type = 1, and Type = 3 will be allowed. So I will be forced to remove it on each view. With function I will have only one place to change.

Comment: You could add a bit field to `mainData`.  Something along the of `ActiveFilter`, which is true for 1, 2 and 3 only.  Should the types change later on all you would need to do is update the new field accordingly.

Comment: If it's always on the same couple of table you can create a view.

Comment: juergen d is 100% correct.  Do not use a table function the performance will suffer.  It's really not necessary to do.

Just do this (mainData.Type IN (1,2,3))

Comment: Inline table value functions do not have the performance hit of scalar or multi-statement table value functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view like this:

```
  create view dbo.FilteredMainDataTable
  as
     select ...
     from dbo.MainDataTable 
     where [Type] in (1,2,3);
```

And then use this view in all your queries instead of dbo.MainDataTable. What the compiler does then it "opens" the view as its definition in every query that uses this view and that is what you want. Functions do not do this and they are not thought as "macro substitution"

If you insist on function you can create it but it will not have a "look" as you want. It can be inline table-valued function like this:

```
create function dbo.fn_FilteredMainDataTable(@n1 int, @n2 int, @n3 int)
returns TABLE
    return select Id, ...
    from FilteredMainDataTable
    where type in (@n1, @n2, @n3);
```

Then you join to this function instead of MainDataTable like this:

```
SELECT main.SomeValues, mainData.Name
FROM dbo.MainTable main
JOIN dbo.fn_FilteredMainDataTable(1,2,3) mainData ON main.dataId = mainData.dataId
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The following code shows how inline table function like a view push in the seek predicate:

```
    if object_id('dbo.num') is not null drop table dbo.num;
    go

    select top 1000000
           isnull(row_number() over(order by 1 / 0), 0) as n,
           isnull(row_number() over(order by 1 / 0), 0) as n1
    into dbo.num
    from sys.columns c1 cross join sys.columns c2 cross join sys.columns c3;
    go

    alter table dbo.num add constraint PK_num_n primary key (n);
    go

    create index ix_n1_n on dbo.num (n1, n);
    go

    if object_id('dbo.fn_num_between') is not null drop function dbo.fn_num_between;
    go


    create function dbo.fn_num_between(@n1 int, @n2 int)
    returns table
    as
       return 
       select n, n1
       from dbo.num
       where n between @n1 and @n2;
    go

    select *
    from dbo.fn_num_between(1, 1000)
    where n1 = 5;
```

[image: seek predicate]

Comment: Still prefer function :)

Comment: @DiPix but for no real or valid reason other than a sense of "beauty".

Comment: Functions generally don't allow 'predicate push' like views do, which is an optimisation trick that might just cause you a large issue in future. Databases are not applications and applications are not databases.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Can you supply a proof link, please? I've just tested the inline function similar to that from my answer and the predicate was successfully pushed in. I can post my repro if you wish

Comment: Oh that's interesting! No I don't have a proof link, I can only say that the more complicated a construct, the less likely the planner is to be able to unwind it to push a predicate through, and generally speaking, someone without a database background is more likely to misuse a function in this way (because as we know, they are very handy for reuse). I certainly believe you and I'd be interested in seeing a repro but this may not be the forum for it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I can add the repro to my answer, I just don't know how to paste the code in the comments and comments also have a size limit. I think this repro also touch the "function" topic so it's nothing wrong to post the repro here. But if you prefer, I can post it on sql.ru, the language of that forum is Russian but I can post there and give you a link here, how do you prefer?

Comment: I realise now it makes perfect sense to edit your original question and add the code in there - then you can code format it too.

Comment: My original answer, you mean :) The question of this kind definitly is not mine :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an inline table valued function.
You would define the function as:

```
create function fnFilteredTypes ()
returns table as return
(
        select 1 as type
        union
        select 2 as type
        union
        select 3 as type

);
```

Then you can join against this function like so:

```
SELECT main.SomeValues, mainData.Name
FROM dbo.MainTable AS main
JOIN dbo.MainDataTable AS mainData
    ON main.dataId = mainData.dataId
JOIN fnFilteredTypes() As typeFilter
    ON(mainData.Type=typeFilter.type)
```

I'm not sure this query is really what you want, but basically you get the idea that you can use the function like it's a parameterized view & join directly against it's fields. Just don't forget it's a function & you call it with round brackets.